# Full path to running script?

Tags: centos

LInux CentOS 7

To show is running my bash script I use this in terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep myScript.sh
```

And here result:

```
root      6886 31386  0 10:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto myScript.sh
```

Nice. But I also need to show full path to myScript.sh.

Smt like this:

```
 root      6886 31386  0 10:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /etc/application/scripts/myScript.sh
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't seem to be running here, the process displayed as output is grep and not your script.

Let's try to explain with an example:

I use `grep` to find if the process `script.sh` is running, I use the following command :

```
ps -ef | grep script.sh
```

If the process is running you will have the following result :

- The process (script.sh)
- The grep process searching for script.sh

Like this :

```
root      842310  842214  0 08:14 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./script.sh
root      842338  842299  0 08:14 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto script.sh
```

The process with PID `842310` is my running script.

So make sure your script is running ;)

For the path I don't know if you can get it. I have tried several methods but have not succeeded.